# Commutator bracket identities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how commutator brackets $[J,K]=[J,P]+[J,X]$  results in the form $K=P-X$, where $J$, $K$, $P$, $X$ are 3$\times$3 matrices. What is the identity behind this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$[J,K]=[J,P-X]=J(P-X)-(P-X)J=JP-PJ+(-JX+XJ)=[J,P]+[X,J]$.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer is quite useful.